# SOLVED: Adding error messages to an array in bash procedure

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here I placed working example, solved thanks to all you and completed with comments:

```
#!/bin/bash

errors=()  #array to store all errors
to=""      #a variable
DEST=""    #another variable
from=""    #and so on

e=$(mv "$from" "$to" 2>&1) #this command makes first error
if [ -n "$e" ] ;then errors+=("$e"); fi  #and this save it to array

e=$(mv "$DEST" "$to" 2>&1)   #so this makes second error
if [ -n "$e" ] ; then errors+=("$e"); fi #and this saves it to array

if [ ${#errors[@]} -eq 0 ]; then #if no errors
   echo OK
else           #if there are error (YES)
    echo "ATTENZIONE: SI SONO VERIFICATI DEGLI ERRORI DURANTE L'OPERAZIONE DI RESTORE:"
    for t in "${errors[@]}"; do  #display all errors 
      echo "$t"
    done
fi
```

Thank you very mutch.

---

This is the first answare before the solution:

I need to add to an array all error messages in my bash file.
Thanks to  shellcheck.net and Cyrus and Freddy I adjusted code:

I did it:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x    #DEBUG
errors=()
to=""
DEST=""

if ! mv "$from" "$to" ; then errors+=("$?"); fi

if ! mvv "$DEST" "$to" ; then errors+=("$?"); fi

if [ ${#errors[@]} -eq 0 ]; then 
   echo OK
else
    echo "ATTENZIONE: SI SONO VERIFICATI DEGLI ERRORI DURANTE L'OPERAZIONE DI RESTORE:"
    for t in "${errors[@]}"; do
      echo "$t"
    done
fi
```

the output that I obtain is :

```
ATTENZIONE: SI SONO VERIFICATI DEGLI ERRORI DURANTE L'OPERAZIONE DI RESTORE:
0
0
```

How can I do to obtain the right error messages in my array "$errors" ?

Thanks

Comment: Change Errors+=($er) to Errors+=("$er")

Comment: no, it does'nt work!

Comment: Double quote your variables and please use consistent lowercase variable names. 
It might also make sense to call your script with `sudo` instead of using `sudo` inside the script. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is your friend.

Comment: I made this adjustment but it isn't working

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: wow shellcheck is fantastic!!! I didn't know of it!

Comment: But still it doesn't work. now I obtain a lot of 0

Comment: If a command like `mv` fails, do you want to save error output (eg "No such file or directory"), or numeric info like exit status (eg 0 or 1) ?

Comment: the first, I'd like save the error string. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't getting the exit status of the command (e.g. `mv "$from" "$to"`), but of the *negated* command (e.g. `! mv "$from" "$to"`) -- since the command failed (nonzero exit status), the negated status is success (zero). In order to do this, you need to avoid negating the status between the command and when you record the status. The easiest way I know of to do this is to use `||` instead of `if`, like this:

```
mv "$from" "$to" || errors+=("$?")
```